# Test-Path with variables and dashes in folder names

Tags: powershell

I have a set of folders I have a naming scheme like
`03 - March` and so on.

I need to test the path and If true, I can't get the quotes or escapes correct.
Here is my code

```
$year = Get-Date -Uformat %Y
$month = Get-Date -Format MMMMMMMM

Test-Path "C:\thisyear\$month - $year"
```

I have also tried

```
Test-Path "C:\thisyear\$month '- $year"
```

That does not work either

Comment: Running your code yields something like `C:\thisyear\July - 2018`, which doesn't match your naming scheme.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-Format` parameter of `Get-Date` to contain any character as a literal (or quoting literal parts as shown in [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51161165/test-path-with-variables-and-dashes-in-folder-names/51161588?noredirect=1#comment89311493_51161588)'s comment) by escaping it with a backslash, so this script:

```
$Folder = Get-Date -F 'C:\\yyyy\\MM - MMM'

If (!(Test-Path $Folder)){
    "create folder {0}" -f $folder
    #  MD $Folder | Out-Null
} else {
   "folder {0} exists" -f $folder
}
```

will output

```
create folder C:\2018\07 - Jul
```

The command to create the folder is commented out, to enable it remove the `#`

Comment: Nice, though embedding literals in a format string is not misuse, it is a [documented feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#character-literals), but you should either `\ `-escape _all_ such chars. individually, or use _embedded_ quoting (though `\ ` chars. still need to be represented as `\\ `): `Get-Date -Format '"C:\\"yyyy\\MM - MMM'`

Comment: @mklement0 According to `The "d", "f", "F", "g", "h", "H", "K", "m", "M", "s", "t", "y", "z", ":", or "/" characters in a format string are interpreted as custom format specifiers rather than as literal characters.` I may have had to escape the colon, but to my experience it is simply copied. The `C` as a literal doesn't need escaping. I included a link to your quoting hint. Thanks for that..

Comment: Thanks; correct, `C` doesn't strictly need escaping, and neither do spaces nor `-`. That said, a viable approach in service of conceptual clarity is to _categorically_ use embedded quoting / individual `\ `-escaping for _all_ embedded literals, whether they strictly need it or not; e.g.: `Get-Date -Format '"C:\\"yyyy\\MM" - "MMM'`'

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `-Format` parameter of [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-5.1) to produce the desired date format.

It appears you want a two digit numerical year, `yy`, separated by `-` from the full name of the month, `MMMM`.

```
$Date = Get-Date -Format "yy - MMMM"
Test-Path "C:\thisyear\$Date"
```

This [MSDN page has the full list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo(VS.85).aspx) of available format operators.